# Is $4x^2−1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain

Is $4x^2−1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ .

I think yes as the roots of the polynomial are not integers so it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, but it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as we could factor out the polynomial as a product of two linear factors and the roots are rational so it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Next I encounter this theorem
If $f(x)$ is irreducible in $D[x]$ ($D$ is an Integral domain) then it is also irreducible in $F[x]$,where $F$ is the field of Quotients of $D$

now comparing this above
as $4x^2−1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ it must be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ , but we saw above that it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Any mistake here?

Comment: $4x^2-1=(2x-1)(2x+1)$.

Comment: Oh yes I thought it as $(x - \frac{1}{2})(x + \frac{1}{2})$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is a field and $\Bbb Z$ is not.

Comment: nice one@DHMO.I missed that point,so I cannot write it as $(x - \frac{1}{2})(x + \frac{1}{2})$ as that requires the inverse of $4$!

Comment: $(x-\frac{1}{2})(x + \frac{1}{2})$ isn't even equal to $4x^2 - 1$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely trivial. $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is *no*. Infact
$$4x^2-1=(2x-1)(2x+1)$$

and both factors belong to $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $4x^2- 1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as we can write the polynomial as linear factors as $(2x + 1)(2x - 1)$ which shows reducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

But we cannot factor the above polynomial as $4(x - \frac{1}{2})\cdot(x + \frac{1}{2})$ as factoring that requires the inverse of the $x^2$ term coefficient which doesnot exist in $\mathbb{Z} $ as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

So the above polynomial is both reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.